# Using client side certificates with objective-c under macosx with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ssl, macos, certificate, client-side

I am looking for sample code or documentation on how to use client side certificates with SSL  under MacOSX.

The server I want to connect to, does speak a custom ascii protocol but allows only ssl connections with registered client certificates. I already wrote a client in Java that works.

In Java I initialized a SSLContext with a KeyManager-Array and a TrustManager-Array. How would I do that with Objective-C on MacOSX?

I found this http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/ which got me as far as connecting and receiving from a server that does not require a client certificate. Would it be feasible to extend that code to use client side certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want **CFStream**

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Concepts/Concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH4-SW4

Comment: Thanks! I actually got it working with cocoaasyncsocket and your hint to CFStream assured me that I was on the right track.